# Javascript 2D Array Issue Changing Specific Element Changes Column

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I go to change the value of lets say terrain[2][3], it will change the whole column rather than just that specific coordinate. The first function creates the Array while the second function defines the terrain of 1's and 2's.

```
var ArrayMaker = function(cols, rows, con1, con2) {


var array = []
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    array[i] = con1
    for (var j = 0; j< rows; j++){
      array[i][j] = con2
    }
  }
  return array
}

var setup = function() {
  var terrain = ArrayMaker(height/50, width/50, [], 1)

  var nLakes = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
  for (var i = 0; i < nLakes; i++){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (terrain.length + 1))
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (terrain[1].length + 1))
    console.log(x + " " + y)
    terrain[x][y] = 2

  }
  console.log(terrain)
}
```

Output that I receive when running the executed code. As you can see the columns itself are being repeated and I have tried changing them outside the function to get the same effect. I'm new to Javascript itself and I may just be defining the 2D array wrong.

```
18 25
14 23

(20) [Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38), Array(38)]
0
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
1
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
3
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
4
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
5
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
6
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
7
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
8
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
9
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
10
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
11
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
12
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
13
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
14
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
15
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
16
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
17
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
18
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
19
:
(38) [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
length
:
20
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your initialisation code assigns the same `con1` array (which initially is []) to all rows of your new array. So you actually only have one row with several references to it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
  array[i] = con1
  /* ... */
}
```

Change this using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
  array[i] = con1.slice(); // Now it is a separate copy
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed the issue, can you explain the splice() function, I don't understand how it worked and fixed the issue. I'll mark your comment as an answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: `slice` will create a new array from a given array, by copying each value from the given array. `slice` allows to specify arguments to only copy part of the array, but without arguments, it copies the whole array. The same can be achieved with spread syntax: `array[i] = [...con1];` or with `array[i] = Array.from(con1);`. Choose whichever you find easiest.

Comment: pls refer this to learn about slice [MDN Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). you can also use `[].concat(con1)` to copy an array